# How can I show data only in line chart form that my conditions are "Province" is "กรุงเทพ" and "Year" is "2018"

Tags: json, flutter, dart, pub.dev

Detail graph

> x : Month ---> Jan,Feb,March,...
>
> y : The average rainfall

I can show my line chart with my all API data (x = month  , y = the average of rainfall), but I want to show line chart that the only scope are:

1. only in Province is กรุงเทพ
2. only in 2018 (1 years from all)

so all in all, the result shows only 1 graph

the average of rainfall in each month that graph shows only province in Bangkok data (กรุงเทพ)  and in 2018

That's my code

1. Line chart code with API

   ```
   import 'dart:convert';

   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_report/RainfallThai.dart';
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
   import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

   class LineCharts extends StatefulWidget {
     const LineCharts({super.key});

     @override
     State<LineCharts> createState() => _DashBoardDBState();
   }

   class _DashBoardDBState extends State<LineCharts> {
     List<RainfallThai> usersA = [];

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: const Text("Line Charts"),
           backgroundColor: Colors.pink[300],
         ),
         body: Container(
           child: SfCartesianChart(
               primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
               title: ChartTitle(text: 'ปริมาณน้ำฝน'),
               legend: Legend(
                 isVisible: true,
               ),
               tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
               series: <ChartSeries<RainfallThai, String>>[
                 LineSeries<RainfallThai, String>(
                   dataSource: usersA,
                   xValueMapper: (RainfallThai monthai, _) => monthai.MonThai,
                   yValueMapper: (RainfallThai avgrain, _) =>
                       num.tryParse(avgrain.AvgRain),
                 ),
               ]),
         ),
         floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
           onPressed: fetchUsersA,
           backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
           child: Icon(Icons.auto_graph_rounded),
         ),
       );
     }

     void fetchUsersA() async {
       print('LINE CHART called');
       const urlA = "https://v1.nocodeapi.com/synatic/csv2json/pOWwVHFulerJvWnC";
       final uriA = Uri.parse(urlA);
       final responseA = await http.get(uriA);
       final bodyA = responseA.body;
       final jsonsA = jsonDecode(bodyA);
       final jsonA = jsonsA['json'] as List<dynamic>;
       final transformedA = jsonA.map((obj) {
         return RainfallThai(
             ProvinceName: '',
             EngName: '',
             toID: '',
             MonThai: obj['MonThai'],
             MinRain: '',
             MaxRain: '',
             AvgRain: obj['AvgRain'],
             region: '',
             Year: '',
             Month: '',
             Date: '');
       }).toList();
       setState(() {
         usersA = transformedA;
       });
       print('LINE CHART completed');
     }
   }
   ```
2. `RainfallThai()`

   ```
   class RainfallThai {
     final String toID;
     final String ProvinceName;
     final String EngName;
     final String MinRain;
     final String MaxRain;
     final String AvgRain;
     final String region;
     final String Year;
     final String Month;
     final String Date;
     final String MonThai;
     RainfallThai({
       required this.toID,
       required this.ProvinceName,
       required this.EngName,
       required this.MinRain,
       required this.MaxRain,
       required this.AvgRain,
       required this.region,
       required this.Year,
       required this.Month,
       required this.Date,
       required this.MonThai,
     });
   }
   ```

   3. my API data (in JSON form) ---> not all data because it's too big

   [image] -------> that is my api JSON pics ;)

   4.that's my line chart that all in api data
3. [image] --------> that's my graph that show all of API
   detail graph

> x: Month ---> Jan, Feb, March,...
>
> y: The average rainfall

I want to show this but only in my conditions that

1. Province is กรุงเทพ
2. Only in 2018

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).